# XSLT 1.0: extract sequential infromation from external document

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to use xslt to perform an xml to xml transform, such that each element is given a GUID, pulled in sequential order from an external xml document.

Source xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dataSets>
  <data name="foo"/>
  <data name="bar"/>
  ...
</dataSets>
```

List of IDs:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ids>
  <id>some-GUID</id>
  <id>another-GUID</id>
  ...
</ids>
```

Desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dataSets>
  <data name="foo" id="some-GUID"/>
  <data name="bar" id="another-GUID"/>
  ...
</dataSets>
```

But I'm just getting the same, first ID each time:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dataSets>
  <data name="foo" id="some-GUID"/>
  <data name="bar" id="some-GUID"/>
  ...
</dataSets>
```

So far this is the xsl I've got:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/|node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dataSets">
    <xsl:for-each select="data">
      <xsl:variable name="c">
        <xsl:number value="count(preceding-sibling::*|self::*)"/>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
          <xsl:value-of select="document('idList.xml')/ids/id[$c]"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>

    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

I've tried adding `<xsl:attribute name="num"><xsl:value-of select="$c"/></xsl:attribute>` to the xsl to see what the variable is each time it iterates and it starts at 1 and increments each time through the `for-each` just as I'd expect so I've no idea why it's not working.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you know which `guid` need to be assigned to the `<data>`? Solely by seeking the element at the same position?

Comment: Same position will work; the `guid` doesn't need to be matched to the data in any explicit way, I simply want to be able to select the next ID in the list so that each data has a unique ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="data">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:variable name="i" select="count(preceding::data) + 1" />
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="document('idList.xml')/ids/id[$i]"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note**:

1. If all `data` elements are siblings under the same `dataSets` parent, you can expedite this by counting only the preceding siblings:

   ```
   <xsl:variable name="i" select="count(preceding-sibling::data) + 1" />
   ```
2. There are probably better ways to assign GUIDs to nodes.

---

### Addditional explanation:

The reason why your attempt does not work is a combination of two factors:

First, the way you define your variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="c">
   <xsl:number value="count(preceding-sibling::*|self::*)"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

results in the variable being a **result tree fragment**. The variable contains a single root node, and the string generated by `xsl:number` is a child of that node.

Next, you try to use the variable as a **numeric predicate** in the expression:

```
<xsl:value-of select="document('idList.xml')/ids/id[$c]"/>
```

However, since the variable is *not* a number, it is evaluated as a boolean - and being non-empty it returns true, causing *all* `id` nodes to pass the test (and, of course, in XSLT 1.0 `xsl:value` will only return the value of the first one of these).

**How to fix it:**

There are three ways you can fix this problem:

1. Do not use the variable as a numeric predicate. Instead, put it in an expression that compares it to the position explicitly (as suggested in the answer by @potame):

   ```
   <xsl:value-of select="document('idList.xml')/ids/id[position()=$c]"/>
   ```
2. Convert it to number before using it as a predicate:

   ```
   <xsl:value-of select="document('idList.xml')/ids/id[number($c)]"/>
   ```
3. Eliminate the problem right from the start by defining the variable using the `select` attribute, which will cause the variable to become a number to begin with:

   ```
   <xsl:variable name="c" select="count(preceding-sibling::*|self::*)" />
   ```

See also:
http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#variable-values
http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates

Comment: There's something weird. When the variable is defined and set with a `@select`, it works fine but if it is set with a content model (nested `<xsl:number>` or `<xsl:value-of>` like in the original post), it fails. Any idea on why this behaviour?

Comment: @potame Because then it's not a number. As a rule, it's always preferable to use the `select` attribute when populating a variable - for more reasons that I can go into in a comment.

Comment: @potame I have added a more detailed explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to slighly change the instruction to retrieve element at the desired index, by the use of `position()`:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="document('idList.xml')/ids/id[position() = $c]"/>
```

I suggest you to use a variable to avoid parsing the document several times:

```
<xsl:template match="dataSets">
    <xsl:variable name="idList" select="document('idList.xml')/ids"/>

    <xsl:for-each select="data">
        <xsl:variable name="c">
            <xsl:number value="count(preceding-sibling::*|self::*)"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="$idList/id[position() = $c]"/>
            </xsl:attribute>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$c" />
        </xsl:copy>

    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: There's no harm in introducing the variable, but it's unnecessary. Because of the rules for the stability of the document() function, the processor is pretty well forced to cache the result anyway.