# XSL dynamic index

Tags: xslt

```
<xsl:variable name="columnIndex1">
    <xsl:value-of select="position()+1"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="var5" select="/mxRoot/columns/column[($columnIndex1)]/settings/setting[@name='Show Function']" />
     javascript:link("<xsl:value-of select="@index"/>","<xsl:value-of select="$oid"/>","<xsl:value-of select="$relId"/>","<xsl:value-of select="$parentId"/>","<xsl:value-of select="$parentId"/>","<xsl:value-of select="$var5"/>")
</xsl:variable>
```

In this var5 is getting always first index only, not getting dynamic index

Comment: The underlying problem is the same as in the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29823166/xslt-1-0-extract-sequential-infromation-from-external-document/

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your variable like this :

```
 <xsl:variable name="columnIndex1" select="position()+1"/>
```